# Config web.xml for restful web service

Tags: android

I am created restful web service and config web.xml like this still i got " HTTP Status 404 - /RestWebServiceModel/rest/person"

type Status report

message /RestWebServiceModel/rest/person

description The requested resource is not available.

```
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 

xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

RestWebServiceModel

```
<servlet-name>RestWebServices</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

<init-param>

    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>

    <param-value>com.avilyne.rest.resource</param-value>

</init-param>

<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
<servlet-name>RestWebServices</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Is your rest service returning json? What are you using for Json jackon jars? What is the version of jersey jars you are using?

Comment: I am not created any thing in the client side.

Comment: I did not ask about client side. Post more details version fo jersey jars etc.

Comment: jersey 2.8.  Json only